# Acumatica Rest API get Business Account

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm trying to receive Business Account info through the rest API. I try with a filter and without the filter. It is using the default end point and the default BusinessAccount.   The results of both runs are below after the code.

My code to get the Acumatica content

```
        public async void GetCustomersActivitiesAsync(int top, string filterOperation, string filter)
    {

        string url = settings.url + settings.endpoint + "BusinessAccount";
        string parametersFilter = "&$filter=BusinessAccount eq  'ABARTENDE'";

        var uri = new Uri(url + parametersFilter);
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                err = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                try
                {
                    ResponseMessage msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseMessage>(err);
                    if (msg != null && msg.exceptionMessage != "") err = msg.exceptionMessage;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    err = ex.Message;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            err = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

When I run the filter it fails auto manically
When I do a filter it returns this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1"><link href="/A000/Content/font-awesome.css?timestamp=636698449900000000" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="/A000/App_Themes/Default/00_Controls.css?timestamp=636698449900000000" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><title>
 Error Has Occurred
</title><meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .main
        {
            padding-left: 40px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            padding-top: 30px;
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        .errCode
        {
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 15pt;
        }
        .errMsg
        {
            font-size: 12pt;
        }
        .img
        {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .nxtSt
        {
            margin-top: 30px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 15pt;
        }
        .navTo
        {
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
        .errPnl
        {
            padding: 10px;
            padding-top: 15px;
        }
        .grayBox
        {
            border: solid 1px #CCC;
            background-color: #F9F9F9;
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 20px;
        }
        .traceLnk
        {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
<style type="text/css">
 .frmBottom_CaptionL { background-position:left top;width:5px; }
 .frmBottom_CaptionR { background-position:right top;width:5px; }
 .frmBottom_CaptionM {  }

</style></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="./Error.aspx" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken" id="__RequestVerificationToken" value="Aq4LEYY5T50IzZfjFHxJWWVP0lq4kLBG-ljIPF3eUYBdBo3UHLHNgHdHF8YW9hpS3nHqiATSFrDybUkJvaXapM_ZItg1" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="frmBottom_state" id="frmBottom_state" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__SmartPanelVisible" id="__SmartPanelVisible" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="L10nEditor_state" id="L10nEditor_state" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="inputBox_state" id="inputBox_state" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var __appPath = '/A000/';var __nodePath="";var __nodeGuid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";//]]>
</script>

<script src="/A000/PX.ScriptBatch.axd?d=cFBYLldlYi5VSXxQWC5XZWIuVUkuRXh00&amp;t=636698318120000000" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/A000/PX.ScriptBatch.axd?d=cFBYLldlYi5VSXxQWC5XZWIuVUkuQmFzZQ2&amp;t=636698318120000000" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/A000/PX.ScriptBatch.axd?d=cFBYLldlYi5VSXxQWC5XZWIuVUkuRWRpdA2&amp;t=636698318120000000" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/A000/PX.ScriptBatch.axd?d=cFBYLldlYi5VSXxQWC5XZWIuVUkuR3JpZA2&amp;t=636698318120000000" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var __loadImgUri = "/A000/App_Themes/Default/Images/spinner.gif?imgTimeStamp=636698449900000000";
var __loadStr = "";
var _numbFormatInfo = {negativeSign:"-",currencySymbol:"$",percentSymbol:"%",number:{groupSeparator:",",decimalSeparator:".",groupSizes:[3],negativePattern:1,decimalDigits:2},currency:{groupSeparator:",",decimalSeparator:".",groupSizes:[3],positivePattern:0,negativePattern:0,decimalDigits:2},percent:{groupSeparator:",",decimalSeparator:".",groupSizes:[3],positivePattern:1,negativePattern:1,decimalDigits:2}};
var _dateFormatInfo = {am:"AM",pm:"PM",shortDate:"M/d/yyyy",shortTime:"h:mm tt",longDate:"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy",longTime:"h:mm:ss tt",timeSeparator:":",yearFix:0,monthNames:"January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December,",abbrMonthNames:"Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,",dayNames:"Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday",abbrDayNames:"Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat"};

__createPxContext(window);
var __PXFormView = {maxFileSizeMsg:"The file exceeds the maximal allowed size (25000 KB).",allowedFiles:".als;.cer;.csv;.dat;.doc;.docx;.epl;.exe;.gif;.ico;.ics;.jpeg;.jpg;.js;.mdb;.msi;.ofx;.pdf;.pfx;.ppt;.pptx;.qbo;.qfx;.rar;.rtf;.sql;.swf;.txt;.xls;.xlsx;.xml;.zip;.zpl;.pbix;.png;.svg;.tif;.tiff",allowedFilesMsg:"Only the following file types are allowed: {0}.",callbacks:[{name:"Refresh",repaintControls:1,blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"Search",repaintControls:1,blockPage:1},{name:"Save",repaintControls:1,blockPage:1,commitChanges:1},{name:"Delete",repaintControls:1,blockPage:1},{name:"AddNew",repaintControls:1,blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"NoteShow",blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"NoteSave",repaintControls:3,blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"FilesMenuShow",blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"ActivityShow",blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"LinkShow",repaintControls:3,blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"LinkUpdate",repaintControls:3,blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"LinkSend",repaintControls:3,blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"NotifyMenuShow",repaintControls:3,blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"NotifyShow",repaintControls:3,blockPage:1,commitChanges:1,postData:0},{name:"CheckActivity",blockPage:1,postData:0},{name:"UploadFile",blockPage:1}],errorCss:"FormError",warningCss:"FormWarn",infoCss:"FormInfo",minHeight:63,filesMenuUrls:{filesDisplayUrl:"~/Frames/GetFile.ashx",fileInfoUrl:"~/Pages/SM/SM202510.aspx"}};
var _frmBottom = {allowCollapse:0,minHeight:0,autoSize:{enabled:1,container:1}};
var _confirmMsg = "Any unsaved changes will be discarded.";
var __PXSmartPanel = {callBackMode:{blockPage:1,postData:0}};
var _L10nEditor = {loadOnDemand:1,autoReload:1,commandName:"SaveLoc",autoCallBack:{behavior:{postData:0}}};
var __PXInputBox = {activeEnter:0,buttonCss:"MessageButton",autoAdjustSize:1,callBackMode:{blockPage:1,postData:0}};
var _inputBox = {};
//]]>
</script>

    <div class="main">
        <div name="frmBottom" id="frmBottom">
  <div style="position:relative;">
   
                <div class="errCode">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="grayBox">
                    <div class="img">
                        <img id="frmBottom_imgMessage" tabindex="100" src="../App_Themes/Default/Images/Message/error2.gif" border="0" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="errMsg">
                        <span id="frmBottom_lblMessage" class="errMsg">We're sorry! An error has occurred while processing your request. A report has been generated for our technical staff to investigate the problem. Please try to repeat your request later. Thank you for understanding.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="traceLnk">
                    <a id="frmBottom_lnkTrace" tabindex="101" href="Trace.aspx"><u><font color="Blue" size="4">Show Trace</font></u></a>
                </div>
                <div class="nxtSt">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="navTo">
                    
                    
                    
                </div>
    
            
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <table name="L10nEditor" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="L10nEditor" tabindex="300" class="SmartPanel" style="display:none;">
 <tr>
  <td id="L10nEditor_cap" class="SmartPanelC" valign="middle"><div class="sprite-icon control-icon" icon="Close" mode="c" style="float:right;">
   <div class="control-icon-img control-Close">
    &nbsp;
   </div>
  </div>Translations</td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td class="SmartPanelCN" id="L10nEditor_cont" width="0" height="0"><div class="panelContent">

  </div></td>
 </tr>
</table><table name="inputBox" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="inputBox" tabindex="400" class="SmartPanel" width="400" style="display:none;">
 <tr>
  <td id="inputBox_cap" class="SmartPanelC" valign="middle"><div class="sprite-icon control-icon" icon="Close" mode="c" style="float:right;">
   <div class="control-icon-img control-Close">
    &nbsp;
   </div>
  </div>Copy to clipboard (Ctrl+C)</td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td class="SmartPanelCN" id="inputBox_cont" width="400" height="0"><table tabindex="400" border="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td><input name="inputBox$ctl01" type="text" class="editor" /></td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td align="right"><button type="button" class="MessageButton Button">OK</button><button type="button" class="MessageButton Button">Cancel</button></td>
   </tr>
  </table></td>
 </tr>
</table></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, don't have any advice on this `post` but https://www.getpostman.com/ is super useful for debugging APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query parameters, such as `$filter`, are separated from the path by `?`. In your case that should give `<base url>/BusinessAccount?$filter=<filter espression>`.

Comment: so it should look like this? for example `string url = settings.url + settings.endpoint + "BusinessAccount?$filter=BusinessAccount eq 'ABARTENDE";`

Comment: Basically, yes, but be careful, as you've lost a closing quote.